# The preimage of a basic open set of a continuous function is always a basic open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,T), (Y, U) topological spaces, $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous function. Is the preimage of a basic open set in Y always a basic open set in X? Is the preimage of a subbasic open set in Y always a subbaisc open set in X?

Here basic open set is an element of a basis, subbasic open set an element of a subbasis.

Comment: What do you mean by a (sub)basic open set?

Comment: No. For instance , consider $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology and $f$ a constant function (with $Y$ any topological space)

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I've edited it. Here basic open set is an element of a basis, subbasic open set an element of a subbasis.

Comment: @Brandon If U is a basic open set of Y, whenever U contains the constant p, the preimage of U is X, whenever U doesn't contain p, the preimage of U is $\emptyset$.

Comment: @user136592 Yes, and you can't express, for example, the open set $(0,1)$ as an union of $X$ or $\emptyset$ so the collection $\{X,\emptyset\}$ is not a basis for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: (As a note apart, every open set is trivially a basic open set and a subbasic open set, since all of the topology is)

Comment: @Brando Oh, yes. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very confusing: It seems that you are fixing a basis of Y and allowing arbitrarily bases of (X,T). If this is what you have in mind, then the answer to your question is tautologically positive, as one can declare the entire T to be a basis of T.

Comment: ...I didn't notice this, but yes, your interpretation is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

No. For an example, take $X:=Y:=\Bbb R^2$ with the same Euclidean topology, but with the open disks as a basis for $X$ and the open squares as a basis for $Y$, and take $f:={\rm id}$.

Comment: But U is a basic open set, if there exists a basis B s.t. B contains U.